# Outlined TextInputEditText in latest design support library 28.0.0-alpha1

Tags: material-design, android-support-library

After upgrading to design support library 28.0.0-alpha1 as part of the Android P preview and updating my base app theme to extend from `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar` according to the documentation at https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md all my textfields now show the filled version as show below.

## [image: Filled version of TextInputEditText]

Is there a way to change to the outlined version using the design support library instead of having to refactor to android.x and switching to using the new material components?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that using support design library in your gradle

Add this line:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

- Note: You should not use the com.android.support and com.google.android.material dependencies in your app at the same time.
- Use com.android.support or androidx

You may get render error then add this line in style AppTheme
`<item name="cardViewStyle">@style/CardView.Light</item>`

you can refer this link [readme](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mdc-101-java/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0)